# How to set sorting in default repository function in Typo3?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have written like this

```
/**
 * itemRepository
 *
 * @var \KRT\KrtEmployee\Domain\Repository\ItemRepository
 * @inject
 */
 protected $itemRepository = null;

/**
 * action list
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction()
{
    $arguments =$this->request->getArguments();     

    $employees = $this->itemRepository->findAll();        
    $this->view->assign('employees',$employees);
}
```

In my **$employees** result I have

- Employee ID (Default uid)
- Name
- Designation
- Department
- Salary

Now, How can I Sort the result array in **ascending** order based on

1. Name
2. Department and Salary

Is there any default function to sort inside the repository queries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every repository has a `$defaultOrderings` property where you can specify the default orderings applied to all query methods. In your case it could look like this:

```php
protected $defaultOrderings = [
    'name' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
    'department.name' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
    'salary' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
];
```

As you can see with `department.name` you can also sort by properties of relations. Notice that this only works for 1:1 and n:1 relations.

In case of custom query methods in your repository you can manually set the orderings directly on the query:

```php
$query->setOrderings([
    'name' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
    'department.name' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
    'salary' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple options depending on what you would like to achieve:

**Setting a default order for the entire repository**

Add the following to your repository class

```
protected $defaultOrderings =
    array(
        'department' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
        'salary' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
    );
```

This will apply to all queries made in this repository.

see: https://wiki.typo3.org/Default_Orderings_and_Query_Settings_in_Repository

**Setting an order for a single query**

Add this to a query you define in your repository

```
$query->setOrderings(
    array(
        'department' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
        'salary' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
    )
);
```

In this way you could (and would have to) implement a different access method for each sort order you would like to have returned.

see: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

**Sort the result**

You can always use PHP sorting methods to sort the query result (possibly converting it to an array with `->toArray()` first.

Comment: Thank you very much for detail explanation, if I want only needed to sort one result I have written in controller like this `$this->itemRepository->setDefaultOrderings(array('name' => QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING));
$employees = $this->itemRepository->findAll();` is this correct? Now I'm getting it as an non-sorted array

Comment: This should work, yes. Do you receive the non-sorted array with our without setting the default orderings?

Comment: NO, from the method you suggested I'm receiving the sorted array. only this method returns the non-sorted array. Maybe I have gone wrong anywhere. My issue has been solved with the method you suggested, I just checked this method if it may be needed in future. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general and complete:

```
<?php
namespace <yourVendor>\<yourExtensionkey>\Domain\Repository;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface;

class <yourDomain>Repository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {

    protected $defaultOrderings = [
        '<yourProperty1>' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
        '<yourProperty2>' => QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING
    ];
}
```

Further explanation in [docs.typo3.org](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/2a-creating-the-repositories.html)